# Does this look like to much grease built up on the gears in this drill casing?

Tags: drill, motor

So I’m mixing cement with my dads Stanley drill (Stanley Industrial 91722 1/2 ALL PURPOSE DRILL MODEL.01 RPM 425 AMPS 4.3 VOLTS 115AC) and have done small batches until today. It seems like I burned the motor. I opened of the casing and noticed all this grease on the gears. Is this normal or should I clean some of this out?

[image]

Comment: I don't think the grease is your problem. Does the drill still work?  I don't think that drill is meant for mixing cement.

Comment: Normal for it to be grease packed, bad to be ancient dirty grease. I would repack it, assuming you can fix/replace whatever you "burned up"...

Comment: grease looks normal.  next time use a smaller beater to stir the cement,